# bash file can not cat string after reading line of file

Tags: bash

I have a list file each line has a format like "0,[0-9]". I write following code in bash file:

```
while read line 
do
   grep $line Search.txt
done < list.txt
```

but I do not get any result as when I write

```
command="$line Search.txt"
echo $command
```

I get only

```
Search.txt
```

and $line becomes NULL.
What is the problem here with bash or using while for reading file?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables.

Comment: Sounds like you could use `grep -f list.txt Search.txt` instead of the loop.

Comment: Does the file contain a blank line?

Comment: exactly I want to implement grep -f by reading file in bash format.
I have no blank line.
I have a problem with printing $line in terminal when other string added after $line (e.g. grep $line Search.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am reading your question correctly and the latter block (using `$line`) is something you ran after the first block (with `while` loop), if so, the following happens:

`while` runs until `read` "failed", i.e. most likely reached EOF. But that last `read` call still took place and "nothing" head been read into `line`. See below.

You could save this value from within the loop by for instance:

```
while read line; do
   grep $line Search.txt
   last=line
done < list.txt
```

Where last line read would be accessible after the your is through the loop through value of `last` variable.

---

As mentioned above, an practical explanation of what happens with that `while` loop. Let us have file `f`:

```
aaa
bbb
```

And a script `example.sh` (basically an unrolled loop, since we know number of passes):

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
echo ${?}: \"$line\"
read line
echo ${?}: \"$line\"
read line
echo ${?}: \"$line\"
```

Which upon running `./example.sh < f` yields:

```
$ ./example.sh < f
0: "aaa"
0: "bbb"
1: ""
```

Side note: after that last (`read`) call, past your `while` loop. The variable actually is set, but is assigned an empty string (`""`) value.